# How are electric under blankets fail safe?

Tags: heat, insulation

Electric under blankets are mains powered and yet you lie on them.  240V in the UK. They appear to effectively be a single resistive heating element. Clearly they're not earthed as that would be difficult, and I can't see how double insulation could apply.

It seems to me that if the element breaks, it could poke through the material and cause a shock hazard to the sleeper.  And what if my old dog wees on it, or bites it?  If they were a danger, they wouldn't be sold.  So how are they made fail safe?

Comment: Usually in the manual says: It is not allowed to sleep on blanket, you may only heat the bed, but then it has to be removed.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Citation please. I have never seen such an instruction in about 40 years. Heat the bed and then unmake it to remove the blanket? Every night? I don't think so.

Comment: @user207421 "then unmake it to remove the blanket?". No just unpluging from mains is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 2001, all electric blankets now have a safety mechanism that will kill power if it detects that the element is broken. Many are now operated using 12 or 24VDC as well, so there is less danger of shock if something goes awry; the control unit is also a DC power supply.

If your dog wees on it and the element is not already damaged, nothing will happen, the heating element wire is insulated. But you can't really wash it, so don't let that dog on the bed!

Comment: Ah!  That's something I should have added. Modern ones are fully machine washable which sounds like another way to break the elements.

Comment: So is that a current sensor?

Comment: This answer is using broad strokes without any evidence. All? Many? 2001? For what country, the uk? relevant law?